# How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have query like this and it gives me single-row subquery returns more than one row error:

```
SELECT COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CUSTOMERS)
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM TRANSACTIONS)
```

Which tries to get count of distinct PERSONNEL_ID from customers table where CUSTOMER_ID at customers table and CUSTOMER_ID at transactions table are equal

Can you tell me how to fix my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one customer in `transactions`.  Presumably, you intend:

```
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM TRANSACTIONS)
```

Which you can also phrase as:

```
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ANY (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM TRANSACTIONS)
```